# Trying to upgrade/install several packages on vagrant VM

Tags: python, vim, vagrant, virtual-machine

I am trying to install some packages in my linux ubuntu VM using vagrant. I am trying to install vim in this example but other packages have failed as well.

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ sudo apt-get install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
libgpm2 libpython2.7 python2.7 python2.7-minimal vim-common vim-runtime
vim-tiny
Suggested packages:
gpm python2.7-doc binfmt-support ctags vim-doc vim-scripts indent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libgpm2 libpython2.7 vim vim-runtime
The following packages will be upgraded:
python2.7 python2.7-minimal vim-common vim-tiny
4 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,494 kB/13.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 27.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python2.7 i386 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python2.7-minimal i386 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libpython2.7 i386 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did you try as it suggested ?

Comment: run apt-get update? Yep no Dice

Comment: `apt-get update --fix-missing` ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install vim`.